# Extracting from an R output

Tags: r

I am doing regressions using the GETS package in R.

However, I would like to extract only the P-values from the final model estimated.

Here is an example of the full output,

```
Date: Wed Apr 24 08:34:44 2019 
Dependent var.: indreturns[, "RM_E"] 
Method: Ordinary Least Squares (OLS)
Variance-Covariance: Ordinary 
No. of observations (mean eq.): 593 
Sample: 1969(9) to 2019(1) 

GUM mean equation:

       reg.no keep     coef std.error
mconst      1    0 0.523354  0.187838
ar1         2    0 0.010603  0.064269
mxreg       3    0 0.047547  0.042493
        t-stat   p-value
mconst 2.78620 0.0055045
ar1    0.16498 0.8690194
mxreg  1.11895 0.2636151

Diagnostics:

                     Chi-sq df    p-value
Ljung-Box AR(2)     0.92272  2 6.3043e-01
Ljung-Box ARCH(1)   8.91110  1 2.8344e-03
Jarque-Bera       105.50599  2 1.2293e-23

Paths searched: 

path 1 : 2 
path 2 : 3 2 

Terminal models: 

spec 1 : 1 2 3 
spec 2 : 1 3 
spec 3 : 1 

                info(sc)       logl   n
spec 1 (gum):     5.8785 -1733.3972 593
spec 2:           5.8678 -1733.4088 593
spec 3:           5.8634 -1735.3071 593
                k
spec 1 (gum):   3
spec 2:         2
spec 3:         1

SPECIFIC mean equation:

          coef std.error t-stat  p-value
mconst 0.53341   0.18556 2.8746 0.004191

Diagnostics and fit:

                    Chi-sq df    p-value
Ljung-Box AR(2)     3.2264  2 1.9925e-01
Ljung-Box ARCH(1)  11.1504  1 8.4013e-04
Jarque-Bera       117.9227  2 2.4741e-26

SE of regression     4.5187
R-squared            0.0000
Log-lik.(n=593)  -1735.3071
```

I would only like this to the output,

```
SPECIFIC mean equation:

          coef std.error t-stat  p-value
mconst 0.53341   0.18556 2.8746 0.004191
```

I have tried to extract but this is the part I am struggling with.

Comment: can you assign the output to an object? If so, what options do you have when you use `$` after the object?

Comment: also check the class of the output, if it's S4 there should be a way to extract specific parts using a function (like `pvaue(output)`) or something, which should be listed in any help documentation

Comment: Can you post the code you used? Not just the output.

Comment: Use the "str" function on your output object, and identify how to access it.